How to directly address main memory (RAM) in OS omitting virtual memory?
I write this just for hypothetical consideration. What steps should one take in order to get a physical address to RAM memory, omitting virtual memory, under Linux OS? I know somewhat about STM32 embedded programming, and there are clear docs and manuals that describe peripheral addresses on the device. Where should one look for these addresses? Motherboard/CPU vendor manuals? I suppose that such an application must run with kernel privileges. Are there some libraries? I know the risk of potentially damaging memory which other processes or the OS use.

Embedded systems, where you have direct access to the hardware (including RAM) are very different from PC-like systems running Linux or Windows. User-space application in Linux or Windows (or macOS for that matter) just doesn't have, and shouldn't have such direct access to hardware.

With the above said, what is the actual problem you have? What are you really trying to do? Why do you think direct non-virtual access to RAM would solve your problem? Please [edit] your question to ask about the actual and underlying problem directly, instead of making your question an XY problem.

@Someprogrammerdude probably he wants to do some hardware register level programming in Lunux userspace.

Take a look at the Linux kernel sources. I'd also suggest grabbing a book on that topic, which guides you through the kernel code a bit.

@UlrichEckhardt kernel source will not help here -  he wants userspace. nmap man page will be more suitable :)

You mean mmap, @0___________. ;)

I don't understand what mmap can do here, honestly. I assume that the addresses mentioned above are physical addresses, as is often the case for embedded stuff, at which device register files are located. Even if you know those, mmap doesn't give you access to them from user space.

At the level of hardware, you don't omit virtual memory, you simply make use of it.  Each virtual address is mapped to a physical address via the page tables, so if you have kernel privileges, you just set the page tables to map some convenient virtual address range to the physical addresses you want to access.  Sometimes it's convenient to set up an "identity mapping" where a given physical address range is mapped to by the same range of virtual addresses.


Where should one look for these adresses? Motherboard/CPU vendor
manuals?

Yes in the IC documentation. The problem is that it is not usually available for people who do not have NDA signed and were not accepted by the vendor.
Under Linux, if your app is being run with sufficient privileges you can access the registers using mmap.
Example (RPI) - simplified to use only 32bit access and volatile paramers:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

// Define Raspberry Pi SPI base address
#define BCM2835_PERIPH_BASE  0x3F000000  // For Raspberry Pi 2/3/4
#define SPI0_BASE            (BCM2835_PERIPH_BASE + 0x204000)  // SPI0 base address
#define PAGE_SIZE            4096
#define BLOCK_SIZE           4096

// Define SPI register offsets
#define SPI_CS    0x00  // SPI Control and Status
#define SPI_FIFO  0x04  // SPI FIFO data
#define SPI_CLK   0x08  // SPI Clock Divider
#define SPI_DLEN  0x0C  // SPI Data Length
#define SPI_LTOH  0x10  // SPI Loss of Clock Ticks
#define SPI_DC    0x14  // SPI DMA DREQ Controls

// Function to write to a register
void write_register(volatile uint32_t* base, uint32_t offset, uint32_t value)
{
    *(base + (offset / 4)) = value;
}

// Function to read from a register
uint32_t read_register(volatile uint32_t* base, uint32_t offset)
{
    return *(base + (offset / 4));
}

int main()
{
    int mem_fd;
    void *map_base;
    volatile uint32_t *spi_base;

    // Open /dev/mem
    if ((mem_fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Cannot open /dev/mem");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Map the SPI registers into memory
    map_base = mmap(NULL, BLOCK_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, mem_fd, SPI0_BASE);
    if (map_base == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap failed");
        close(mem_fd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    spi_base = (volatile uint32_t *)map_base;

    // Example: Write and read the SPI_CLK register
    uint32_t clock_divider = 0x800;  // Set SPI clock divider
    write_register(spi_base, SPI_CLK, clock_divider);

    uint32_t read_value = read_register(spi_base, SPI_CLK);
    printf("SPI_CLK value: 0x%08X\n", (unsigned)read_value);

    // Clean up
    if (munmap((void *)map_base, BLOCK_SIZE) == -1)
    {
        perror("munmap failed");
    }
    close(mem_fd);

    return 0;
}

Or if you want to access hardware using I/O port space (also vendor specific)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Define I/O ports for Super I/O chip (example for Nuvoton NCT6775)
#define SIO_INDEX_PORT   0x2E
#define SIO_DATA_PORT    0x2F

// Registers for fan speed (example values, check your chip's datasheet - I do not have it)
#define FAN_SPEED_REG_LSB  0x04  // Fan speed low byte
#define FAN_SPEED_REG_MSB  0x05  // Fan speed high byte

// Enter the Super I/O configuration mode
void enter_superio_config()
{
    outb(0x87, SIO_INDEX_PORT);
    outb(0x87, SIO_INDEX_PORT);
}

// Exit the Super I/O configuration mode
void exit_superio_config()
{
    outb(0xAA, SIO_INDEX_PORT);
}

// Select a logical device (e.g., Hardware Monitor LDN)
void select_logical_device(uint8_t ldn)
{
    outb(0x07, SIO_INDEX_PORT);
    outb(ldn, SIO_DATA_PORT);
}

// Read a register from the Super I/O chip
uint8_t read_register(uint8_t reg)
{
    outb(reg, SIO_INDEX_PORT);
    return inb(SIO_DATA_PORT);
}

// Read fan speed (16-bit value)
uint16_t read_fan_speed()
{
    uint8_t lsb = read_register(FAN_SPEED_REG_LSB);
    uint8_t msb = read_register(FAN_SPEED_REG_MSB);
    return (msb << 8) | lsb;
}

int main()
{
    if (ioperm(SIO_INDEX_PORT, 2, 1) != 0)
    {
        perror("Failed to get I/O permissions");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    enter_superio_config();
    select_logical_device(0x04);  // Logical Device Number (LDN) for Hardware Monitor
    uint16_t fan_speed = read_fan_speed();
    exit_superio_config();

    printf("Fan Speed: %u RPM\n", (unsigned)fan_speed);

    ioperm(SIO_INDEX_PORT, 2, 0);
    return 0;
}

